# SQL Real Time queries

Tags: mysql

is there a way or a software to see in real time queries to a mysql server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool like Microsoft's "SQL Server Profiler" for MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124925/is-there-a-tool-like-microsofts-sql-server-profiler-for-mysql)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124925/is-there-a-tool-like-microsofts-sql-server-profiler-for-mysql) question. Doesn't look too good, sorry.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes there is. Its called SQL Profiler. You should be able to install it from the SQL server media

Comment: This question is about MySQL, he doesn't have SQL Server media.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the SQL tag so it threw me. its now removed